# SQL query clarifications required

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

[image: Data is present in the below format]

I want to fetch the multiple-row data into a single row in Oracle as per the below. A maximum of 2 records can be available and min 1 record in the table for the given enquiry_id comlumn.

[image: Need data in below format]

I have tried the row number function etc. But not getting data in a valid format

WITH cte_enq AS (SELECT
ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY enquiry_id
) row_num,
status,
skip_disclaimer,
queue_name
FROM
FMP_CUSTOMER.cibil_enquiry
)

SELECT queue_name,status,skip_disclaimer FROM cte_enq
WHERE row_num =1;

Answer (score 2):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` and then `PIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT enquiry_id,
       "1_QUEUE_NAME" AS queue_name_0,
       "1_STATUS" AS status_0,
       "1_SKIP_DISCLAIMER" AS skip_disclaimer_0,
       "2_QUEUE_NAME" AS queue_name_1,
       "2_STATUS" AS status_1,
       "2_SKIP_DISCLAIMER" AS skip_disclaimer_1
FROM   (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY enquiry_id ORDER BY ROWNUM ) AS row_num,
         enquiry_id,
         status,
         skip_disclaimer,
         queue_name
  FROM   FMP_CUSTOMER.cibil_enquiry
)
PIVOT  (
  MAX(status) AS status,
  MAX(skip_disclaimer) AS skip_disclaimer,
  MAX(queue_name) AS queue_name
  FOR row_num IN (1 AS "1", 2 AS "2")
);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE FMP_CUSTOMER.cibil_enquiry (enquiry_id, status, skip_disclaimer, queue_name) AS
SELECT 1, 'A', 'B', 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'D', 'E', 'F' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'G', 'H', 'I' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'J', 'K', 'L' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ENQUIRY_ID | QUEUE_NAME_0 | STATUS_0 | SKIP_DISCLAIMER_0 | QUEUE_NAME_1 | STATUS_1 | SKIP_DISCLAIMER_1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | C | A | B | F | D | E |
| 2 | I | G | H | L | J | K |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/EKLDlId8)

Answer (score 2):

here is a dynamic query that return for each enquiry_id return all rows in one row:

```
DECLARE
    sql_stmt CLOB;
    max_rows NUMBER;
    i NUMBER := 1;
BEGIN
    FOR c IN (SELECT enquiry_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM FMP_CUSTOMER.cibil_enquiry GROUP BY enquiry_id) LOOP
        sql_stmt := 'SELECT enquiry_id, ';

        max_rows := c.cnt;  -- Get the count of rows for the current code

        FOR i IN 1..max_rows LOOP
            sql_stmt := sql_stmt || 'MAX(CASE WHEN rn = ' || i || ' THEN status END) AS status' || i || ', ';
            sql_stmt := sql_stmt || 'MAX(CASE WHEN rn = ' || i || ' THEN queue_name END) AS queue_name' || i || ', ';
        END LOOP;

        sql_stmt := RTRIM(sql_stmt, ', ') || ' FROM (SELECT status, queue_name, enquiry_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY enquiry_id ORDER BY id) AS rn FROM FMP_CUSTOMER.cibil_enquiry  WHERE enquiry_id = :enquiry_id) GROUP BY enquiry_id';

        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt USING c.enquiry_id;

        -- Execute the query with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE and use the fetched result accordingly
        -- Here, you can process or display the result set
        -- Note: The fetched result needs to be handled further based on your use case
    END LOOP;
END;
```